# What is >> (double chevron) in far field communication

Tags: antenna, far-field

I keep seeing this notation with no justification or explanation as to what it is – it appears to be being used as greater than but I don't know why > isn't sufficient. Didn't want to ask it as a separate question but I think it needs to be.

Comment: Could you provide some context? I think it's meant to express that it's really far field, as in orders of magnitude further than what you could still consider near field.

Comment: @LukeHappyValley look on the 'near and far field' Wikipedia page. The first use of the notation should have a mention as to why its being used but it doesn't, so I will be adding it.

Comment: Typically, in textbooks, ">>" means " *much* greater then".

Comment: -1 for not including the context where you found the symbol used.

Comment: @ThePhoton down votes are Ill constructive, not only do you lose reputation, I lose reputation, and it only motivates me to delete the question. Context is in the comments

Comment: We ask you to edit your question to include all the important information. Mods might delete the comments at any time to clean up the site, so understanding the questoin shouldn't be dependent on reading the comments.

Comment: Also, note that downvotes on a question do not cost the voter anything at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"<<" and ">>" mean "*much* less than" and "*much* greater than", respectively — where "much" implies "by at least an order of magnitude" (a factor of 10 or more).

The implication is that the smaller quantity has no significant effect on what follows.